# Eclipse type declaration points to wrong package

Tags: eclipse, jar, package, declaration

In eclipse when I control click or select an object an hit "F3", I get directed to a class in a **jar** instead of the **package** in eclipse.
Of course the jar content has the same class as the package in eclipse but I don't want it to search there.
How can I fix the folders for the so called "Open Declaration"?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the `import` is the right one ?

Comment: Yes, removed it and added it again, this is not the issue, your answer seems logical, i'll mark it as correct when I don't get a better one, even though in my case I can't do it.

Comment: That is weird, because eclipse usually opens a popup with a list of classes from the different possible packages in case of ambiguity...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so a colleague of mine found the answer, attached you can see a picture of the packages "Order and Export". The "JBoss 4.2 ..." was on 2nd place from the top and the actual package where he should have searched (top arrow) was almost on the bottom. I changed the ordering as pictured, now it works perfect.[image]

Comment: Had same problem. So hard information to find... ! Works like a charm ! I had multiple projects, so I only had to add them in "project" tab.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `import` from your project corresponding to this class is the right one, and that you chose a package name different from the one used in the jar file :

Rename your class, or suppress the ambiguity by prefixing your class name by the package name in your code. Right now, I don't see any other option.

```
org.test.MyClass c = new org.test.MyClass();
```